# How to sum all appearances from list and print maximum value from list

Tags: python, list, printing

Hello I have qeustion about web scraping. How to print max, min and average from scraped data? Also I don't know how to connect it with appearances from tiitle. The final print would look like this :

```
BMW - number of offerts: ..., max price:..., min price: ..., average price: ...
```

I created a list with this data, but I don't know how to sum appearances of tiitle, and count max,etc values from this.
Here is my code:

```
    for car in carList:
      

        title = car.find('a', class_='offer-title__link').text.strip()

        price = car.find('span', class_='offer-price__number').text.strip()


        lista = [title, price,]


        carFile.write(title + ',')
        carFile.write(price + ',')

        carFile.write('\n')

        print( lista)
        print(lista.count(title))

carFile.close()
```

for now i only count a tttle.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
Calculating a mean is documented in many places.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: Your posted code has a *lot* of overhead that is superfluous to your question.  Remove the overhead of scraping itself: start with *only* the resulting data (a list).  Implement your attempt to find the mean: *that* is the start of your MRE.

Comment: Ok I changed my question. I am begining, and I don't know many things in programing.

Comment: maybe you should keep it in different structure then nested list - ie. dictionary `{"BMW": [items_for_bmw], "AUDI" : [items_for_audi], ...}`. OR put all in `pandas dataframe` and it has many functions to select elements and make calculations - ie. `df[ df["title" ] == title ]["price"].mean()`

Comment: better first search cards with offer and later search title and price in this offer and create pairs `single_title, single_price` and add this pair to list. And then you can filter all offers by title and get prices. In current version you would first create pairs `zip(title, price)` to filter it.

Comment: frankly, your previous code seems more useful for me - it could be used it as minimal working code and test ideas for solution (PL:  prawdę mówiąc poprzedni kod wydawał się dla mnie bardziej użyteczny - można go było wykorzystać jako minimalny działający kod i testować pomysły na rozwiązanie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to analyze data then better put all in `pandas.DataFrame`

First add `[title, int(price)]` to external list `data`

```
data = []

for page in range(1, last_page+1):

    # ... code ...

    for car in car_list:

         # ... code ...

         data.append( [title, int(price)] )
```

And later convert to `DataFrame`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['title', 'price'])
```

And then you can analyze it

```
    cars = df[ df['title'].str.contains("BMW") ]

    print('count:', len(cars))
    print('price min    :', cars['price'].min())
    print('price average:', cars['price'].mean())
    print('price max    :', cars['price'].max())
```

You can even run in `for`-loop for more cars

```
for name in ['BMW', 'Audi', 'Opel', 'Mercedes']:

    print('---', name, '---')

    cars = df[ df['title'].str.contains(name) ]

    print('count:', len(cars))
    print('price min    :', cars['price'].min())
    print('price average:', cars['price'].mean())
    print('price max    :', cars['price'].max())
```

You can even plot histogram for prices to see which prices are more popular

[image]

[image]

You can even simply save data as `csv` or `excel`

```
df.to_csv('carData.csv')
df.to_excel('carData.xlsx')
```

---

Minimal working code based on your previous code

It displays histograms which you have to close to see next data.

```
import requests
import bs4
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

url = 'https://www.otomoto.pl/osobowe/seg-sedan/?search%5Bfilter_float_price%3Afrom%5D=3000&search%5Bfilter_float_price%3Ato%5D=5000&search%5Bfilter_float_engine_capacity%3Afrom%5D=2000&search%5Border%5D=created_at%3Adesc&search%5Bbrand_program_id%5D%5B0%5D=&search%5Bcountry%5D='

response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()

# check how many pages are there
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
last_page = int(soup.select('.page')[-1].text)

print('last_page:', last_page)

data = []

for page in range(1, last_page+1):

    print('--- page:', page, '---')

    response = requests.get(url + '&page=' + str(page))
    response.raise_for_status()
    
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    all_offers = soup.select('article.offer-item')

    for offer in all_offers:
        # get the interesting data and write to file

        title = offer.find('a', class_='offer-title__link').text.strip()
        price = offer.find('span', class_='offer-price__number').text.strip().replace(' ', '').replace('\nPLN', '')

        item = [title, int(price)]
        data.append(item)
        print(item)

# --- work with data ---

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['title', 'price'])
df.to_csv('carData.csv')
#df.to_excel('carData.xlsx')

for name in ['BMW', 'Audi', 'Opel', 'Mercedes']:
    print('---', name, '---')
    cars = df[ df['title'].str.contains(name) ]
    print('count:', len(cars))
    print('price min    :', cars['price'].min())
    print('price average:', cars['price'].mean())
    print('price max    :', cars['price'].max())        
    
    cars.plot.hist(title=name)
    plt.show()
```

Result:

```
--- BMW ---
count: 3
price min    : 4500
price average: 4500.0
price max    : 4500
--- Audi ---
count: 12
price min    : 3900
price average: 4500.0
price max    : 4900
--- Opel ---
count: 12
price min    : 3300
price average: 4049.5
price max    : 4999
--- Mercedes ---
count: 27
price min    : 3000
price average: 4366.555555555556
price max    : 5000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it its exacly what i was looking for. Thanks for help!

Comment: I have another question. I change  item to   item = [title, float(price)], beacuase it was problem with converting data. But now, when price isn't integer i have error like this:


`ValueError: could not convert string to float: '132770,2`

Comment: it seems page uses `,`  as separator - `132770,2` - but `float` needs `.` - `132770.2` - You have to use `float( prince.replace(",", ".") )`

Comment: I have another question. I tried to find the most common brand in voivodships. I crated function, but I don't know how to print the most common data from another dataframe.
`for voivodships in [ '(Opolskie)',
                 '(Podkarpackie)', '(Podlaskie)', '(Pomorskie)', '(Śląskie)', '(Świętokrzyskie)', '(Warmińsko-mazurskie)', '(Wielkopolskie)','(Zachodniopomorskie)']:
    locations= df[df['location'].str.contains(voivodships)]
    print('---', voivodships, '---')
    print('ilość ogłoszeń w :', len(voivodships))`